# Tracking down memory leak in Google App Engine Golang application?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memory-leaks

I saw this Python question: [App Engine Deferred: Tracking Down Memory Leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189446/app-engine-deferred-tracking-down-memory-leaks)

... Similarly, I've run into this dreaded error:

> Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 128 MB after servicing 384 requests total

...

> After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.

According to that other question, it could be that the "instance class" is too small to run this application, but before increasing it I want to be sure.

After checking through the application I can't see anything obvious as to where a leak might be (for example, unclosed buffers, etc.) ... and so whatever it is it's got to be a very small but perhaps common mistake.

Because this is running on GAE, I can't really profile it locally very easily as far as I know as that's the runtime environment. **Might anyone have a suggestion as to how to proceed and ensure that memory is being recycled properly?** — I'm sort of new to Go but I've enjoyed working with it so far.

Comment: A [heap profile](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) (described at that link along with allocation and CPU profiles) can tell you what's using most of the RAM. [`runtime/pprof`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/) can send a heap prof. to any `Writer` including an `http.ResponseWriter`; you could run that behind some auth in production.

Comment: You could look at this in a different way: upgrade temporarily to the next (1 or 2) instance class(es)  and check the memory usage trend. If it stabilizes after a while the instance class was indeed too small - done :) If it keeps growing (eventually causing an instance restart) then indeed some memory leakage occurs and the investigation *might* be necessary (the instance restart rate *might* be tolerable with the higher instance class). One could look at such restarts as a periodic instance refresh/self-cleaning "feature" allowing, for example, focusing on other, more pressing matters ;)

Comment: @twotwotwo I have that logging now, thanks for the idea.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I might try that, thanks for the recommendation. I actually think I might have found the leak while working with twotwotwo's idea above, but I'll see if it sticks around.

Comment: If you guys want to submit these as answers below I'll vote for both of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a starting point, you might be able to try [`pprof.WriteHeapProfile`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/#WriteHeapProfile). It'll write to any `Writer`, including an `http.ResponseWriter`, so you can write a view that checks for some auth and gives you a heap profile. An annoying thing about that is that it's really tracking *allocations*, not what *remains* allocated after GC. So in a sense it's telling you what's RAM-hungry, but doesn't target leaks specifically.

The standard `expvar` package can expose some JSON including memstats, which tells you about GCs and the number allocs *and frees* of particular sizes of allocation ([example](https://tip.golang.org/debug/vars)). If there's a leak you could use `allocs`-`frees` to get a sense of whether it's large allocs or small that are growing over time, but that's not very fine-grained.

Finally, there's [a function to dump the current state of the heap](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/), but I'm not sure it works in GAE and it seems to be kind of rarely used.

Note that, to keep GC work down, Go processes grow to be about twice as large as their actual live data *as part of normal steady-state operation*. (The exact % it grows before GC depends on `runtime.GOGC`, which people sometimes increase to save collector work in exchange for using more memory.) A (very old) thread suggests [App Engine processes regulate GC like any other](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/nKy7F-73HFQ), though they could have tweaked it since 2011. Anyhow, if you're allocating slowly (good for you!) you should *expect* slow process growth; it's just that usage should drop back down again after each collection cycle.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach to check if your app has indeed a memory leak is to upgrade temporarily the instance class and check the memory usage pattern (in the developer console on the `Instances` page select the `Memory Usage` view for the respective module version).

If the pattern eventually levels out and the instance no longer restarts then indeed your instance class was too low. Done :)

If the usage pattern keeps growing (with a rate proportional with the app's activity) then indeed you have a memory leak. During this exercise you *might* be able to also narrow the search area - if you manage to correlate the graph growth areas with certain activities of the app.

Even if there is a leak, using a higher instance class should increase the time between the instance restarts, maybe even making them *tolerable* (comparable with the automatic shutdown of dynamically managed instances, for example). Which would allow putting the memory leak investigation on the back burner and focusing on more pressing matters, if that's of interest to you. One could look at such restarts as an instance refresh/self-cleaning "feature" :)